# salesforce mobile app with unlimited edition

Tags: mobile

So I tried logging into an unlimited edition instance with the Salesforce Mobile app and according to this: http://www.salesforce.com/mobile/apps/salesforcemobile/comparison/ I should be able to access all objects. However, I don't see any tabs for my custom objects and can't seem to find any records for custom objects by searching.

Is there something else I need to do to enable salesforce mobile vs mobile lite? I'm assuming its the same app it just determines your functionality based on your instance type when you login. Has anyone had experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a mobile configuration an assign it to users/ profiles. The mobile configuration controls what tabs/ objects etc are available to users who are assigned that mobile configuration.

https://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/managing_mobile_configs.htm

Comment: Sure do! Caught me out the first time too...